# Exact same coordinates on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API through the Biostall Library. I am also using the MarkerClusterer function in it.But if I have a couple markers on the exact same location the markers won't split up. What would be the best way to solve this? I was thinking of adding a small random number to those exact same coordinates so that they would be seperate.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think they should split up?

If they are closer than MarkerClusterer's minimum distance (a configurable option) and you are above the maximum zoom (also a configurable option) and your minimum cluster size is 2 (yup, configurable too) then those two markers should appear as a blue cluster of two.

If you zoom enough, you won't see the cluster anymore, just the markers (which is an indication that MarkerClusterer is showing you the original markers). And if the clusters are in the same position, then it isn't up to MarkerClusterer to split them.

Perhaps you should give a look at [OverlappingMarkerSpiderifier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) for that funcionality.

Comment: I need to split them up because I have info windows for each of them. When they are on the exact same location and I zoom in it doesn't split anymore. OverlappingMarkerSpiderifier is kinda the solution I am looking for but is there an alternative? Becuase I am using the Biostall library already.